# Unexpected behaviour with save method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Below is my view and model. Clearly each time I am preparing a fresh `serverRequestData` data for each invocation of `initiateTest` and passing it to `save` method.

So, my server call should happen with data present in `serverRequestData`. It happens correctly for first invocation of `initiateTest` but from second time onwards I see that response of the previous server call is passed.

This looks really weird to me because clearly I am preparing fresh `initiateTest` each time.

What am I doing something wrong which is screwing some internal thing of backbone.js?

**View:**

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'models/adhocmodel', 'models/resultmodel',
        'text!templates/adhoc/adhocTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone,
        adhocModel, resultModel, adhocTemplate) {

    var adhocHistoryView = Backbone.View.extend({

        resultmod : new resultModel(),
        model : new adhocModel(),
        el : $("#container"),

        events : {
            "click #test" : "initiateTest"
        },

        initiateTest : function() {
            var serverRequestData = {"myid":"AAA",
                       "fname":"Wade",
                       "lname": "Wade",
                       "telephoneNumber":telNum,
                       "testMode":"Initial" };

            console.log(serverRequestData);

            var that = this;
            this.model.save(serverRequestData, {
                url: "forms/serviceDiagnostic/startTest",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success : function(model, response) {
                    that.model.adhocCommon.hasTestResultArrived = true;
                    that.model.testResults = response;
                    that.render();
                    $('#container').trigger("create");
                },
                error : function(model, response) {
                    console.log("####### Error recieved ....");
                }
            });
        },

        initialize : function() {
        },

        render : function() {

            console.log(this.model);

            //this.$el.html(adhocTemplate);
            var data = {
                    model:this.model,
                    _:_
            };
            var compiledTemplate = _.template(adhocTemplate, data );

            this.$el.html(null);
            this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);
            return this;
        }
    });

    return adhocHistoryView;
});
```

**Model:**

```
define([ 'backbone' ], function(Backbone) {

    var adhocModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize : function() {

        },

        poolHandler : null,

        poolCounter : 0,

        adhocCommon : {
            hasTestResultArrived : false
        },

        testResults : {}

    });

    return adhocModel;
});
```

Comment: When you say `[...] from second time onwards I see that response of the previous server call is passed`, what do you mean with `passed`? Passed to _what_?

Comment: @try-catch-finally From the second time onwards, console log is correct when data which is really passed to server is wrong. I can see in "network" tab of the browser and also at server side that it is not the same data which is printed, but it is the server's response of last request.

Comment: `that.model.testResults = response` ..? Response will be automatically merged with models attributes by backbone. All your model properties are outside models attribute hash. I think you misunderstood how backbone works. If we have to handle stuff like these manually, then there is  no need of backbone... we can do this the old jquery way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how [`Model.save()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) works. Backbone expects your server to respond with the latest state of the model in server, and your model will be updated with that response.

Also:

> The attributes hash (as in set) should contain the attributes you'd like to change — keys that aren't mentioned won't be altered — **but, a complete representation of the resource will be sent to the server**
>   (*emphasis mine*)

So after your first call, model will be updated with your server response, and from the next time onwards, it'll be sent along with the attributes you pass to `save()`.

If you want to change what is sent to the server, you can overwrite the `save` method, if you want to change what gets updated into model when the response is received, you can define a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your inputs. I have not yet tested again with  your inputs but I guess it will work, looks reasonable.